# Conditional formatting formula to test equality (number of characters within cells)

Tags: google-sheets

I have three columns E, F and G. Inside each column I have cells with characters separated by the delimiter "_".

I am trying to build a conditional formatting formula that checks if each cell has the same equal number of characters (excluding delimiters) and highlights them if they do not.

For example if we have cells E2, F2 and G2 below respectively:

A_B_C_D
1_2_3_4
F_G_H_I

In this case all three have four characters each.

The below formula works however I have only managed to incorporate two columns into it. How can I incorporate the third column into this? In a way that if column G has a number of characters that does not match either column E or F then the highlight will activate?

=COUNTA(SPLIT($E2,"*"))<>COUNTA(SPLIT($F2,"*"))

Answer (score 2):

try this out:

```
=COUNTUNIQUE({COUNTA(SPLIT($E2,"_")),COUNTA(SPLIT($F2,"_")),COUNTA(SPLIT($G2,"_"))})<>1
```

- 

[image]